# Maven Assembly Plugin - Include other child dependencies in assembly

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have four child pom under one parent.  One of the children is to build a zip containing the other 3 modules jars.  This works but it doesn't pick up their respective dependencies.

module-build pom.xml :

```xml
...    
    <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>               
       <inherited>true</inherited>              
       <configuration>
          <descriptors>
             <descriptor>desc.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
       </configuration>   
    </plugin>
...
```

desc.xml :

```xml
...

        <moduleSets>
            <moduleSet>
                <binaries>
                    <unpack>false</unpack>
                    <dependencySets>
                        <dependencySet>
                            <unpack>false</unpack>
                            <scope>runtime</scope>                  
                            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                        </dependencySet>
                    </dependencySets>
                </binaries>
            </moduleSet>
        </moduleSets>
    ...
```

The resultant 'lib' folder is not created.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi solarwind, please comment on the answers (if you need more help) or mark one as correct. At the moment this question is still in the "unanswered" list but since there are already two answers without comments I guess you won't get any more at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have specified the other 3 modules as a dependency of this 4th module, next to being in the modules section of the parent?

If you do, it should work even if you do this:

```xml
<assembly>
 <id>final</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
        <scope>runtime</scope>                  
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a bit late, but no matter :).
You should move your assembly at parent project, but that's not the real problem.

Using version of the plugin :

Here mine, wich is totally functional (but in French, forgive me ;))

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <!-- Ce chemin est lié au plugin maven-jar et à la génération du manifest 
        : à manipuler avec précautions -->
    <id>lib</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <!-- Supprimer la création d'un répertoire dans l'archive au nom du projet -->
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

This is a built-in feature of the plugin (to get dependencies). But I'd never use it from a multimodule project, and I know that there is some tricky consideration with the use ob ModuleSet ...

Hope that will help...